# Android: BackStack misbehaves, if application was started from another app

Tags: android, back-stack, application-close

I have an application, which starts with a `SplashScreenActivity`. Afterwards, a `LoginActivity` is shown, or if the user is already logged in, a `MainActivity` is shown. If the application is already running, `SplashScreenActivity` is dismissed with the following

```
//SplashScreenActivity
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Adding this check for following cases
    if (!isTaskRoot())
    {
        String intentAction = getIntent().getAction();
        if (getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        if(getIntent().getCategories().contains(GCMIntentService.INTENT_CATEGORY_GH_NOTIFICATION)){
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
```

**Problem occurs**

If I start the application from another activity like PlayStore, it resumes at the right activity if already running. This is the `Intent` I'm using to reproduce within a second app

```
//AnotherApplication.apk
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.package.name");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

However, this action is somehow breaking the Backstack. Instead of closing the application on backpress in the `MainActivity`, it restarts the application.

```
//MainActivity.class
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getNavDrawerMain().isDrawerOpen()) {
        getNavDrawerMain().closeDrawer();
    } else {
        closeApp();
    }
}

protected void closeApp() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        //super.onBackPressed();   //i tried both, but behaviour is the same
        finish();
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

I used breakpoints and found out that MainActivity:onDestroy() get called, but instead of resuming application to the HomeScreen, it always restarts and I don't know why.

I tried the following:
- Used different launchmodes like `singleTask` and `singleInstance`, but it didn't make any difference. `onNewIntent` is called, but if i call `finish`, `HomeActivity` restarts
- as commeted below, i tried `moveTaskToBack(true)`, but Activity is restaring too (and we really want to close the app instead of moving it to the BackStack)

Comment: In my experience, `getLaunchIntentForPackage(...)` *does not* return a launcher intent.  A launcher intent will raise the existing task, but the intents returned by `getLaunchIntentForPackage(...)` will actually start a new one.  Your app may not be restarting when you back out of it; you may simply be seeing another copy of it.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: Intent has following type `android.intent.action.MAIN`, i just added some additional code, how i handle the intent

Comment: I can't find anything that explicitly says so, but I suspect that only the system is allowed to receive `ACTION_MAIN`.

Comment: It seems splash activity is always in stack. Did you set it as parent of MainActivity in manifest ?

Comment: Can you show us your Manifest? I wonder if it's connected to your launchmode.

Comment: I am a bit confused with your problem description. To make it clear: Do you mean user: opens Play Store > Open your App > hit back key, at this moment, you want your app to be closed but, it gets restarted, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try with `moveTaskToBack(true);` instead of `finish();` to close the app. It will then go to OnRestart() and then OnStart()->OnResume() (and won't go to OnCreate).

And make sure you don't have the "Don't keep activities" marked at Developer Options in your Android Settings (destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it).

Comment: Make sure you don't have the "Don't keep activities" marked at Developer Options in your Android Settings (destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it).

Answer (score 1):

Trying adding this flag to your intent starting your app: RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED, URL=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED

What it does:

If set, and this activity is either being started in a new task or bringing to the top an existing task, then it will be launched as the front door of the task.

You may also use:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

What it does:

If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running.

Which one you use depend on the desired end result.

If you can't control who starts you you need to set or launch mode to single task or single instance.

Described here:

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

The interesting part:

singleTask

This mode is quite different from standard and singleTop. An Activity with singleTask launchMode is allowed to have only one instance in the system (a.k.a. Singleton). If there is an existed Activity instance in the system, the whole Task hold the instance would be moved to top while Intent would be delivered through onNewIntent() method. Otherwise, new Activity would be created and placed in the proper Task.

Comment: the problem is, that the `Intent` where I should add the flags is started from (in our case) `Google Play Store` or `HockeyApp`, so we cannot change them. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Oh, then you just need a single instance task, updated answer.

Comment: "...tried different launchmodes, but it didn't make any difference..." maybe I should have make this point more clear. I tried `singleTop` , `singleTask` etc...  Doesn't make any difference. I see, that Activity is destroyed, but instead of reuming to prevoius stack, it calls `onCreate()` again

Comment: Post complete logs and describe in detail exactly what you did

Comment: guess i posted the main parts or what else could help? guess i should rebuild this behaviour in a plain project, and commit this to github, but at the moment there s no time for that :-/